# C# - Add List of images to report viewer

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a list of images to select to add it to the report.

After selecting the list of images, How to add all the selected images to the report viewer.

Comment: Could you please provide code samples that you are using

Comment: I know how to add predefined number of images, but here the scenario is, i am not sure about the number of images

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036570/insert-unknown-number-of-images-to-the-report-at-runtime-using-reportviewer

Comment: finally got the solution for my problem. just did some home work and the following link helped me, 'http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/6194/display-image-in-rdlc-report-microsoft-report-viewer.aspx'