# How to add an unknown amount of external images to rdlc report without using database in C#

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am currently working on a project that the user can upload images to the program's specific save folder. Which is created by the program and I want to add these unknown amount of images to the report. I did not use database for this project and I want to stay out of it. How can I do this?

This is my first time doing such a thing and using RDLC report so I am new to it. I know if I were to inclued DB for this it would be easier to manage.

Comment: Maybe dupplicate  from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806768/rdlc-dynamically-add-images-to-report

Comment: The RDLC is HTML format and you can looks at the report in Notepad or any HTML viewer (debugger).