# How to generate QR Code in RDLC ASP.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, qr-code, rdlc

I have build a rdlc report in my ASP.NET MVC5 project and want to add the QRCode at the end of the voucher.
I have searched google a lot but did not find a way how to add the **QRCode in rdlc in ASP.NET MVC5**.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You should generate the QRCode inside your code, convert it to byte image, then embed it inside the report through dataset.

Comment: @5DN1L Can you plz share a sample code!!!

Comment: Which part of this do you need help with? There are library to make QRCode. The generated image can be added to the dataset you are using, be that a database field or a List of objects. The image can be shown in RDLC report with settings like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwWZK.jpg

Comment: You could use LEADTOOLS. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). First create an empty image with Leadtools.RasterImage.Create() then write the QR code using BarcodeEngine.Writer.WriteBarcode(). Finally save it as JPG or PNG using Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs.Save(). To include the saved barcode images into the report, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806768). For more details, see the [Write Barcodes tutorial](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/dotnet-console-write-1d-and-2d-barcodes-to-an-image.html) which has a link to the SDK free evaluation to try it.